# asp.net how can ObjectDataSource access System.Web.UI.Page objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

I use ObjectDataSource as below.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="Item" runat="server" 
                SelectMethod="Grid_DataBind" TypeName="XXX.XXX.XXX" 
                DataObjectTypeName="Controller.Items" UpdateMethod="UpdateRow_Grid"
                InsertMethod="InsertRow_Grid">
```

When InsertMethod fire, everything work fine but ...

```
public IList<Items> InsertRow_Grid(Items item)
    {
        item.ID = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();          
        bool contains = GridSource.AsEnumerable()
                        .Any(row => item.JobID == row.JobID);
        if (!contains)
        {
            GridSource.Add(item);              
        }
        else
        {              
           lblMsg.Text= "This record has already exists.";               
        }
        return GridSource;
    }
```

It doesn't know my label object which is presented in my aspx file.

[image]

I had read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874564/objectdatasource-selecting-method-cant-see-any-other-controls-values) so that I can search proper solution.

But I still don't get how to do.

Every suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you using lblMsg control, inside grid? Please write some aspx contents producing same problem.

Comment: Please share the aspx for creating control "lblMsg".

Answer (score 1):

This is because asp:ObjectDataSource creates new instance of object you specified in "TypeName" property
To use current page object instead of creating new, you need this code:

```
YourObjectDataSource.ObjectCreating += (s, a) => { a.ObjectInstance = this; };
```

Place it in Page_Load or Page_Init

Answer (score -1):

You can add this code to your page

```
...
<asp:Label id="lblMsg" runat="server"/>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="Item" runat="server" 
            SelectMethod="Grid_DataBind" TypeName="XXX.XXX.XXX" 
            DataObjectTypeName="Controller.Items" UpdateMethod="UpdateRow_Grid"
            InsertMethod="InsertRow_Grid">
.....
```